# White screen display without error message in codeigniter after calling my views

Tags: php, codeigniter-2

I am trying to load my view files to redirect the page and I got white screen without any error.

This is my controller snippets:

```
if($this->M_Cart->hmacCompute($refNum,$toPay,$toPayCurrency))
{
  $this->load->view('templates/Navigation', $this->session_data);
  $this->load->view('V_QRRender',$data);
  $this->load->view('templates/Footer',$this->session_data);
}
```

and this is the logs

```
INFO - 2019-01-30 03:41:43 --> Model Class Initialized
INFO - 2019-01-30 03:41:43 --> Controller Class Initialized
INFO - 2019-01-30 03:41:43 --> File loaded: C:\xampp\htdocs\gt_widget\application\views\templates/Header.php
INFO - 2019-01-30 03:41:44 --> Helper loaded: language_helper
INFO - 2019-01-30 03:41:44 --> Language file loaded: language/english/message_lang.php
INFO - 2019-01-30 03:41:50 --> File loaded: C:\xampp\htdocs\gt_widget\application\views\templates/Navigation.php
INFO - 2019-01-30 03:41:50 --> File loaded: C:\xampp\htdocs\gt_widget\application\views\V_QRRender.php
INFO - 2019-01-30 03:41:50 --> File loaded: C:\xampp\htdocs\gt_widget\application\views\templates/Footer.php
```

Comment: `display_startup_errors`

Comment: what do you mean "display _startup_errors"?

Comment: On development systems you can switch on error messages to see why the white screen occurs. Best placed as `php_flag display_errors on` in .htaccess or `display_startup_error = 1` in php.ini

Comment: Also consider to install xdebug and some IDE capable to act as debugger client, e.g. NetBeans. The log does not show any error. The script might conditionally end without any outputs.

Comment: upon checking, the display_startup_error in php.ini was already on. I also try putting it to .htaccess but still no error message displayed

Comment: You can try some `var_dump()` outputs or better use xdebug to trace the flow.

Comment: where I am going to put var_dump()?

Comment: `var_dump($someVar);` wherever you want to inspect

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iSSjeelN5NU

Comment: I tried using var_dump in my controller, seems no problem on that part. but still white screen output